# Meaning of "experience pertaining to computer science and diversity"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm applying for a grant and there is a question in the application form as follows:

> As a grad student in computer science, what has your experience been
>   pertaining to computer science and diversity?

Is it asking about what I have done for the computer science world? How about the meaning of *diversity* here? Does it mean the different things related to computer science?

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Thanks barrie. Yes, in the context of the application, what you told makes sense.

Comment: BarrieEngland, it looks like you've got what we're looking for there. Put it down as an answer and perhaps @Mohsen will accept it.

Comment: @Karl: I wouldn't have suggested it myself, but since you have done so . . .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me, the question invites you to speak of your experience of equality of access to computer science, that is, access without discrimination based on sex, race, creed and so on. The terminology in the context of the application might possibly have a different meaning, but this seems to be the most likely one.